# Intent not extracting extra

Tags: java, android, android-intent, extras

I have this code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.i(TAG, "The id of the selected note is " + id);
    Intent editNote = new Intent(this, TaskEditActivity.class);
    editNote.putExtra(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_ID, id);
    startActivityForResult(editNote, EDIT_TASK_REQUEST);
}
```

And this code that retrieves the extra ***FROM A DIFFERENT ACTIVITY***:

```
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        id = savedInstanceState.getLong(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_ID);
    }
 Log.i(TAG, "Id of note = " + id);
```

In the first code snippet, Logcat says: `The id of the selected note is 2`, but in the second code snippet, Logcat says: `Id of note = 0`. What just happened here? Any solutions to this VERY annoying problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing the state which is saved when an `Activity` is paused and the data delivered to the `Activity` via an `Intent`.

You want to have something like:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
id = extras.getLong(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_ID);
```

The `Bundle` passed to `onCreate()` is the `Bundle` you saved with [the `onSaveInstanceState()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and is not the extras `Bundle` you added to your `Intent`.

Comment: Please look at my clarification in bold.

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the extra in a very wrong way. Replace your second code snippet with:

```
id = getIntent().getLongExtra(TasksDBAdapter.KEY_ID, 0);
Log.i(TAG, "Id of note = " + id);
```

Here's what happens in this code: `getIntent()` returns the `Intent` you created in your first code snippet (the `Intent` that was used to launch the current activity). Then, `.getLongExtra()` returns the attached extra information. If no extra information with that tag and that data type (long) is found, it will return 0.

`savedInstanceState` is used for saving your app's state when it is shut down by the Android system under low memory conditions. Don't confuse these two.